# 3d Global array in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, heap-memory

I am trying to create a global array that takes its size from a command line argument. As of now, my code looks like this:

```
int*** Matrix;
```

and later, in a function, I am doing this:

```
Matrix = new int**[2];
    Matrix[0] = new int*[gridSize];
    Matrix[1] = new int*[gridSize];
    for (int i = 0; i<gridSize; ++i){
            Matrix[0][i], Matrix[1][i] = new int[gridSize];
    }
```

When I try to assign a value to an entry in the array, this throws a segmentation fault. What can I do to solve this? gridSize is an integer read in from the command line.

Comment: `Matrix[0][i], Matrix[1][i] = ...` does not do what you think it does. See also [Three Star Programmer](https://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammerExamples).

Comment: You should really think about your design. Avoid global variables, avoid raw pointers, use a proper matrix class instead, use `std::vector` and `std::array`. Everything else is most likely resulting in a mess sooner or later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `c++`, you can use the advantage of having `STL`

```
#include <vector>
using Array1D = std::vector<int>;
using Array2D = std::vector<Array1D>;
using Array3D = std::vector<Array2D>;

void resizeArray3D(Array3D &array3D, size_t size) {
    array3D = Array3D(size, Array2D(size, Array1D(size)));
}
```

Note that this version of resize will erase all previous data.